# D3.js chart is visible in Internet Explorer 11 but invisible in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, d3.js, svg

I have a very pretty calendar report that I've created on one machine, that shows my company's daily revenue as a color coded block for every day for the past several years. After finally getting a color scheme down and pretty much finalizing it, I went to test it on another machine - and hit a rather large obstacle.

This is the report that I used as a template:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318

It's awesome. And, inside Internet Explorer 11, it looks fantastic. I never would have expected that copying the code and testing the report would produce a blank page, but there it is. On that page, the calendar report is visible. In IE 11. Copying the code to a new html file and opening it, shows nothing. In Firefox, however, everything is visible. as is.

Now, there's a part of that page that points to

```
"//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"
```

And I figured out that in order to make that work in firefox I had to add the http: in front, so that's not my issue.

I'm literally sitting here at my desk staring at two browser windows open and pointing to the same html file. One contains my beautiful report, one is a completely blank page.

Some cursory google searches reveal that IE 8 or lower have issues with the svg. I can't seem to find any references on someone having a similar issue though. Their situation seems to be that with IE10, you need to specify the height and width, not just one or the other, to make sure everything scales properly.

If I could have my way, I'd just run Firefox on all of the machines that are going to run the report, even if it's *just for that one thing*! Alas, I am but a mere peasant coder and so I have to make it work. in the dreaded IE.

Are there any svg/html/d3.js coders out there that can tell me another way to spit out the data I'm using so that I can get what I'm looking for?

Comment: Please revise your title, is it visible or invisible in IE11?

Comment: please correct the title of your question

Comment: It is both. You can see the visible report on the website that advertises the report, but copying the code to an html file and viewing that file shows nothing. I'll post a clarification.

Comment: Check the logs for errors, see if something didn't load correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> copying the code and testing the report would produce a blank page

Because you're outputting invalid HTML. There is no `html` or  `head` element for starters.

Output your code in to a file like `example.xhtml` and open it in Firefox (specifically) as it's XML parser will very quickly tell you what line and column the first XML parser error is occurring on. You are rendering in standards mode instead of quirks though that does not *imply* your page *meets* standards.

```
var m=(document.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat') ? 'Standards' : 'Quirks'; window.alert(m+'-mode.');
```

Comment: Suddenly it makes so much more sense. So Firefox was applying information to make it work, but IE was just refusing to show anything. that gives me a much better starting point. Thanks.

Comment: Usually people say browsers will render differently in quirks mode though it holds the same for standards mode; just because it's got a doctype doesn't mean it will render the same. The XML parser will interpret a file with an `xhtml` extension as application/xhtml+xml; I use this on my live site (XHTML5) and there is no valid reason to use HTML's non-existent error-reporting when you can get work done so much faster with the XML parser. Yeah no problem. :-) Oh and my guess is that IE is interpreting everything as being in the head element.